# Google maps - click event does not trigger on touch screen

Tags: google-maps, events, click

I am using native marker clusterer js file where, by default, click event is declared:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', e => {...})
```

When I click infoboxes and map itself, it triggers - that is what I want. But when screen has touchscreen, it triggers only when clicking on map itself. I tried to change that event to be `mousedown` but it still does not trigger when clicking on infobox at all (both touch and no-touch screen). It seems to me that event is not bubbling up somehow.

**UPDATE**

The issue was handled in the bug

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35824421

and was solved in version 3.27 of Google Maps JavaScript API in December 2016.

Answer (score 0):

Add "domready" event and add your code inside to close the infobox.

```
infobox.addListener("domready", function() {

 $("#close").on("click", function(e) {

              });
}
```